# what is the grammar of "whose works it should be ...."?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> We are all children of one Father, whose Works it should be our
>   delight to study

What is the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: It means _We are all children of one Father. It should be our delight to study the Works of that Father._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Father is capitalised, I'm going to assume it means God. I'm not a bible scholar/theologian, but it would appear to mean something along the lines of "We are all God's children and we should be happy to study and see everything He has created and done".

Do you have a source? Is it from the Bible?

Comment: Thanks...I think you are right...It's just from a science book.